# plotly dash change the language in dcc.datepickerrange

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to change the language to Russian in dcc.datepickerrange, but I don’t understand how to do it.
I saw that you can use moment.js, but I don’t understand how to connect it to dc.datepickerrange?
Can anyone help?